# Notepad++ associated file style

Tags: notepad++

I am working on Notepad++ for programming. I associated C and C++ extensions. But when I double click the file, Notepad opens file, but no style. When I open file in Notepad++, it has got style. How can I solve that?
Best wishes.

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you want to happen? When you double-click the file, it should open in Notepad++ instead of plain Notepad?

Comment: I want to use "Plastic Code Wrap" with syntax highligting. When I open file in Notepad++ menu, it highlight correctly(background is black, basic variable types is yellow etc.) but when I double click the file, it is opened with no theme, no style, no highligting. When I make right click and select "Edit with Notepad++" , it works correctly.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

From a [Notepad++ forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/09443bc2/):

> Settings -> Styler Configurator, then choose the language you wish on
>   the left hand list. You'll notice two file extension boxes in the
>   lower left part of the dialog. One is read-only and has the default
>   extensions associated. The other "User ext." has whatever extensions
>   you add. Don't copy the leading period, and separate multiple
>   extensions with a space, like in xml conf cfg

Added:
It appears that you need to create a shortcut to the file and use the following syntax:

> /(path)/notepad++.exe -l(cpp language) /(path)/(file)

Comment: It is true, but my problem is different. I can highlight correctly, but when I open with double click, there isn't highlighting.

Comment: Double-click from which program?

Comment: Windows explorer.

Comment: How can I do that in pratical way? Can reinstall solve the problem?